# How to create function based on scope context

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that calculates a date.
It updates the scope on callback.
in this case I update  $scope.spotdate, but other times, I will need to update another
field in the scope.
How to do?
I think I saw there it a function creator in Angular. It receives name of field, and 
creates a function based on context.
I cannot remember how

```
this.spotdate = function (curr1, curr2, date, $scope) {

        var dat = { 'Ccy': curr1, 'Ctr': curr2,'date':date }; 
        $http({ 
            method: 'POST', 
            url: 'api/Help/SpotDate', 
            data: dat 
        }).success(function (data) { 
            var response = data[0]; 
            var date = Date.parse(response); 
            $scope.spotdate = date; 
        }).error(function () { 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the $parse service of course.
Took sometime to find it.
This does the job.